# Update Script not working inside the IF statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know what is going wrong with my script below? When I run the script, it show `Command completed successfully`, but somehow the update script within the `IF` statement is not working (the record is not been updated)

```
DECLARE @call_list VARCHAR
SET @call_list = 'Outbound_000'

IF @call_list = 'Outbound_000'
BEGIN
    UPDATE Genesys.TESTs_Hire
    SET contact_info = '#3550322222222'
    WHERE record_id = 167
END
```

Comment: Is there a row with a record_id of 167?

Comment: Does it update without IF - when you just run UPDATE by itself?

Comment: @Jin Yong : Whenever you declare VARCHAR without a size it will take 1 character for that variable, so your assignment value will trim into single charactor. so you have declare VARCHAR with desired size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your VARCHAR declaration a size, e.g.

```
DECLARE @call_list VARCHAR(50)
```

Otherwise, by default it's a size 1. In that case only 'O' of 'Outbound_000' gets assigned to variable @call_list in SET command and after that of course condition

```
IF 'O' = 'Outbound_000'
```

fails.

[Demo of variable assignment](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18c55/6)